# Problem in calculating statistics using group by based on statuses

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a data like below :

```
Table : LeaveRequest

Id    DepartmentId
1     100

Table: LeaveUpdateLogs

Id      RequestedDate             LeaveRequestId     Status
1       2020-01-26 11:55:56       1                  Pending
2       2020-02-24 10:55:56       1                  Accepted
3       2020-02-24 11:55:56       1                  Accepted
4       2020-03-01 09:55:56       1                  Declined
5       2020-03-27 10:55:56       1                  Closed

6       2020-01-09 05:55:56       2                  Pending
6       2020-02-09 05:55:56       2                  Accepted
7       2020-05-12 02:55:56       2                  Accepted
8       2020-06-14 05:55:56       2                  Declined
9       2020-06-15 05:55:56       2                  Closed
```

I want to calculate statistics for between `Start date and EndDate` and want to count statistics for each of the status.

**Expected output: Start Date = 01-01-2020 EndDate = 06-30-2020**

```
Pending =  2 (2020-01-26 11:55:56,2020-01-09 05:55:56)
Accepted = 3 (2020-02-24 11:55:56,2020-02-09 05:55:56,2020-05-12 02:55:56)
Declined = 0
Closed = 2 (2020-03-27 10:55:56, 2020-06-15 05:55:56)
```

**Classes:**

```
public class LeaveRequest 
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LeaveUpdateLogs> LeaveUpdateLogs { get; set; }

    }
    
    public class LeaveUpdateLogs 
    {
    
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset RequestedDate { get; set; }
        
        public int LeaveRequestId { get; set; }
        
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public virtual LeaveRequest LeaveRequest { get; set; }

    }
```

**Query:**

```
var query = from l in context.LeaveUpdateLogs
            where l.LeaveRequest.DepartmentId == 100 &&
            (l.RequestedDate >= fromDate && l.RequestedDate < toDate)
```

Only challenge here for me is to calculate the data for the **same month and same LeaveRequestId**. For example :

```
Id      RequestedDate             LeaveRequestId     Status
4       2020-03-01 09:55:56       1                  Declined
5       2020-03-27 10:55:56       1                  Closed
```

For above data, we have 2 status in the same month and for the same LeaveRequestId i.e 1 but I want to consider last date for that month("2020-03-27") and increment 1  for that status("Closed").

I will really appreciate any help :)

Comment: I would expect your query to contain a group by,,

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I agree but the problem is If I group by "LeaveRequestId" then I wont be able to count the statistics for all statuses I have mentioned in the expected output. So that's the problem. I might do it by faking group by "group l by 1 into g" like that but then I don't know what I will do about the month. I will really appreciate if you can elaborate more on group by what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the "most recent status per leaveupdatelog leaverequestid-month" then generate statistics per status, which would imply to me to be two groupings. The first grouping knocks out the uninteresting statuses and the second counts them

```
var interesting = query.GroupBy(lul => new{lul.LeaveRequestId, D=new DateTime(lul.RequestedDate.Year, lul.RequestedDate.Month, 1)})
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(gg => gg.RequestedDate).First());
```

This groups the data by ID and month of requested date. It means you get groups where there are two members for 2,3 and 4,5 and 8,9 then selects only the latest dated one, removing 2,4,8

Then we can perform another grouping on the remainder

```
var stats = interesting.GroupBy(lul => lul.Status);
```

This realizes a collection where each item in stats has a key of status and a collection of leaveupdatelogs (should really rename that class to be singular, classes shouldn't have plural names) with the data, to whit:

```
foreach(var g in stats)
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key} = {g.Count} ({string.Join(',', g.Select(gg => gg.RequestedDate))}");
```

should produce the output you expect, with the exception that there are no Declined so nothing will print for them. If it's important to not have them "notified by their absence" then perhaps consider another operation to reveal them such as

```
someArrayOfAllStatus.Except(stats.Select(g=>g.Key))
```

You could generate the array of all status from the enum itself or the original query (using select/distinct) depending on whether there are other status in the enum that you never want to show because they aren't in the query

Important to remember that LINQ group isn't like sql group. In sql you have to specify aggregations and throw data away because you can't have a GROUP BY without a SELECT. In LINQ you can, so the group operation literally forms the keyed buckets and puts all the data inside them as a collection, so at any step all the original data is there to be manipulated. In other words, LINQ group just breaks a dataset of X records into Y lots of Z records (where Y * Avg(Z) = X) so you can iterate each Y and do things like "take only the first Z" (which is what we did firstly) or "count and stringjoin all the Z" (which is what we did secondly)

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but the linq query with “except” function will work in Entity Framework?

Comment: Except is a LINQ thing and an SQL thing (`SELECT 1 EXCEPT SELECT 1` gives no rows) so I expect they're mapped.. I'd say to take care though; I don't personally see any point in risking bothering the db with expensive set reduction operations if the values of Status are available in an enum in the code, for example you could turn your stats into a hash set or dictionary, then add any values of enum not already present before you enumerate it

Comment: Its sounds like a great  idea but actually didnt quite understood. Do you mind elaborating more on hast set or dictionary idea or if you can give a sample then it would be great for me to learn something new and implement it. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: For example if you did `var d = stats.ToDictionary()` you'd have a dictionary of "status => (collection of leave update logs)", you could then enumerate `foreach(var s in new []{"Declined","Accepted",...})` and inside the loop do `if(!d.ContainsKey(s)) d[s] = new ListUpdateLogs[];` to insert empty collections for any statuses that aren't represented, like "declined"

Comment: (I forgot that status is a string..)

Comment: Note that you could, alternatively, enumerate the statuses and if there is a dictionary entry for it, output it, else, output 0. I suppose it depends how close to the point of use the data is generated

Comment: ToDictionary() method is not available on "stats". I need to do .Tolist() on stats?

Comment: It shouldn't so much be that it isn't available, it's just that I didn't choose an overload - `stats.ToDictionary(s => s.Key)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231763/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-caius-jard).